# Getting error on function.php

Tags: functions, theme-development

```
<?php
define('TEMPPATH',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'));
define('IMAGES',TEMPPATH."/images");

add_theme_support('nav_menus');
if(function_exists('register_nav_menus'))
{
    register_nav_menus(
    array(
    'main'=>'Main Nav'
    ));
}

if(function_exists('register_sidebar'))
{
    register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=>_('Primary Sidebar', 'primary-sidebar'),
        'id'=>'primary-widget-area',
        'description'=>_('The primary widget area', 'dir'),
        'before_widget'=>'<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'=>"</div>",
        'before_title'=>'<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'=>'</h3>',
    )
    );
}
?>
```

here's my function.php code as i am new to wordpress theme development my first theme will give warning like this

```
Warning: _() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\functions.php on line 17

Warning: _() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\functions.php on line 19
```

as i am new to theme development i am confused for this warnings

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two underscores `__('String to be translated', 'textdomain')`

Also, it looks like you're not using the textdomain in the right way